# Scenario #98 Question

Tags: gloomhaven, gloomhaven-forgotten-circles

Spoiler tags to prevent accidental disclosure.

> Can my Craighart move the fountain?
>
>  It might make the scenario a bit easier to move the fountain closer to the ships, but unlike the 2 tile wall obstacles, it is not listed as special by the scenario rules.

Answer (score 1):

My copy of Forgotten Circles is still in shrink so hopefully this answer is valid based on my understanding of rules and what I would check.

> On the map of scenario what colour is the border around the fountain?  If it green then it is an obstacle and any Cragheart abilities that affect them will after the fountain.
>  [Rules page 14] explain that anything with a green border is an obstacle.  If that scenario which I've not seen doesn't say the fountain is special then I'd assume it can be thrown or destroyed as per abilities.  Even if that makes little thematic sense! [1](https://online.flippingbook.com/view/598058/14/)